# Dynamics CRM Toggle Field Codes Missing

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

We have uploaded some Document Templates for Dynamics 365 but we are unable to right click on the fields in the word document and select "toggle field codes".

We do this in mail merge to format dates correctly and remove blank address lines etc.
It is missing in Dynamics 365 Document Templates. Does anyone know how we can format the date coming out of CRM in a template like this?

This is an example of a field dragged in to a template where we could normally right-click and select 'toggle field codes';

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Could this be useful ? https://crmtipoftheday.com/716/conditional-values-in-word-templates/

Comment: Thanks Alex.  Kind of useful but as mentioned in the comments there, I don't want the user to have to refresh to document once they open it.  It's not quite fully functional.